# How I can get information about process writing in MongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb

In MongoDB there is collection and in this collection added few docs periodically. I turn off my apps which writing in this collection, but this process dont stopped.

How can I get information about IP or writing process name?

Version : MongoDB 2.6.

I tried `tcpdump` sniffed mongo host, but didnt get any information.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a lot of information from the following commands on mongo shell:

```
db.currentOp(true).inprog.reduce(
  (accumulator, connection) => {
    ipaddress = connection.client;
    accumulator[ipaddress] = (accumulator[ipaddress] || 0) + 1;
    accumulator["TOTAL_CONNECTION_COUNT"]++;
    return accumulator;
  },
  { TOTAL_CONNECTION_COUNT: 0 }
)
```

or

```
db.serverStatus()
```

from a linux shell:

```
sudo netstat -anp --tcp --udp | grep -i mongo
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I get a lot of ip addresses, because many apps use MongoDB. How can I get more accurate info about specific collection and ip's write in this collection?

Comment: You can use db.collection.stats(), or access the oplog where you can find the collection and document involved (ns) in any single operation and the operation type (op), but pay attention because accessing the oplog is heavy, so at least avoid to access from your master.